# Can't use SharedPreferences in intended activity

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

There are two classes `MainActivity` and `PickTimeForNotif` in my project. In MainActivity `getSharedPreferences` works just fine, i can save my data and get it back. In PickTimeForNotif, however, the same method seems to do nothing.

Here's my simplified MainActivity class:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), ChangeCupDialogFragment.StringListener {
    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    
    //this is variable i'm saving
    private var drankToday = 0
    
    //function in which i save my value to SharedPreferences
    private fun saveWaterCountToInternalStorage(clickCounter: Int) {
        val sharedPref = this.getSharedPreferences("something", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        with (sharedPref.edit()){
            putInt(getString(R.string.clickCount), clickCounter)
            apply()
        }
    }
    
    //and here i get it from there
    private fun loadWaterCountToInternalStorage(): Int {
        val sharedPref = this.getSharedPreferences("something", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        return sharedPref.getInt(getString(R.string.clickCount), drankToday)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)
        val setupNotifButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.setupNotifButton)

        setupNotifButton.setOnClickListener{
            val notifIntent = Intent(applicationContext, PickTimeForNotif::class.java)
            startActivity(notifIntent)
        }

    }
}
```

In `setOnClickListener` i intend my second activity `PickTimeForNotif`, here it is.

```
class PickTimeForNotif: AppCompatActivity(), TimePickerFragment.OnCompleteListener {
    val APP_PREFERENCES = "settings"
    private val SAVED_FROM_HOUR = "SetFromHour"
    private var FROM_HOUR = 99

    private fun saveTimeToInternalStorage(prefName1: String, Hour:Int) {
        val sharedPref = this.getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE)
        with (sharedPref.edit()){
            putInt(prefName1, Hour)
            apply()
        }
    }

    private fun loadTimeFromInternalStorage() {
        val sharedPref = this.getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE)
        if (sharedPref.contains(APP_PREFERENCES)) {
            sharedPref.getInt(SAVED_FROM_HOUR, FROM_HOUR)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.pick_time_activity)
        saveTimeToInternalStorage(SAVED_FROM_HOUR, 1)
        loadTimeFromInternalStorage()
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"$FROM_HOUR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

In the code above i'm trying to set value (1 for example ) to a `SAVED_FROM_HOUR` key and then get it back and assign to `FROM_HOUR` variable. However, the Toast shows 99, which means that new data wasn't loaded properly. I tried putting all code from `loadTimeFromInternalStorage` and `saveTimeToInternalStorage` to onCreate, but the result is same.

I also tried checking if the Preferences file exists after i call `getSharedPreferences` with

```
if (sharedPref.contains(APP_PREFERENCES))
```

but it does not.

So i'm asking to explain what am i doing wrong and why i can save the data in my MainActivity, but not in the second one. Thanks alot to anyone in advance!!

Comment: `if (sharedPref.contains(APP_PREFERENCES))` is definitely going to prevent it from working. That function tells you if the SharedPreferences file you have *already opened* contains an entry with that key. You never added a preference using `APP_PREFERENCES` as a key--that's the name of your preferences file as a whole. So the code inside the if statement will never be reached. There's no reason to check if the file exists. The SharedPreferences instance itself is the connection to the existing file.

Comment: Also, I dont see that you have assigned the variable again

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thanks! Removed that line, still not working though. I also tried doing the same operations in onCreate method (but without  `if (sharedPref.contains(APP_PREFERENCES))`) after setting content view, but it doesn't work :( Some other problem is still there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `loadTimeFromInternalStorage()`, you are fetching the value but not assigning to variable like this:

```
private fun loadTimeFromInternalStorage() {
        val sharedPref = this.getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE)
        if (sharedPref.contains(APP_PREFERENCES)) {
            FROM_HOUR = sharedPref.getInt(SAVED_FROM_HOUR, FROM_HOUR)
        }
    }
```

Also, in this line `FROM_HOUR = sharedPref.getInt(SAVED_FROM_HOUR, FROM_HOUR)`, the last parameter in getInt() method is the default value so you should make another constant for it or supply it 0.

Comment: I missed this because `FROM_HOUR` is in all caps, but it's not a constant. @gydroponch, by convention, all-caps names are reserved only for constants.

Comment: @UndefinedBug1.0, thank you so much! I completely forgot that `getInt` just returns the value and i have to assign it to  variable, so i just straight copypasted my own code from first activity and didn't do anything with retrieved value. Also had to delete `if (sharedPref.contains(APP_PREFERENCES))`, it was blocking the following code from executing